# Relational database foreign keys in Spring Boot JPA/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I'm using Spring Boot JPA with Gradle. I'm struggling to find a guide that I can follow which focusses on creating a relational database with the correct Syntax for Spring Boot. I had a go but I get this error

```
No property idTestCase found for type TestRun!
```

I want TestRun and TestData entities with a OneToOne relationship with each other, and a TestCase entity that has a OneToMany relationship with TestRun. I reckon that TestRun should contain the foreign keys for TestData and TestCase.

Many times I make changes and it will not build, and when it does build the tables do not look correct, this is what I created:

```
@Entity
public class TestRun {
  @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long testRunId;           
  private Boolean result;
  @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="testData_id")
  private TestData testData;
  @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="testCase_id")
  private TestCase testCase;
}

@Entity
public class TestCase {
  @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long testCaseId;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="testCase",targetEntity=TestRun.class)
  private Collection<TestRun> testRun;
}

@Entity
public class TestData {
  @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long testDataId;
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="testData",targetEntity=TestRun.class)
  private TestRun testRun;
}
```

From the guides it isn't clear to me what goes in `@JoinColumn(name=` some say it needs to link to a field on your POJO and some say it doesn't. If I create the foreign key field in my POJO then I get two foreign key fields in the database table and if I don't it doesn't build at all.

For example from the error I can infer it wants me to add the following fields to TestRun:

```
private long idTestCase;           
private long idTestData;
```

But then my database appears as:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_RUN;
TEST_RUN_ID  
ID_TEST_CASE  
ID_TEST_DATA  
RESULT  
TEST_CASE_ID  
TEST_DATA_ID  
(no rows, 3 ms)
```

I tried setting `@JoinColumn(name=` to the name of the primary key field on the other side of the relationship but again it did not build.

Many thanks

Comment: The mappings look reasonable. What exactly are you doing to create this 'no property found error' error? Running a query? If so, post that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the guide at [JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association%22JBoss%22) to be the most helpful in describing the different mappings.